# WPF - TabControl contained in scrollviewer: avoid to scroll when tabitem exceed the width of the control

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, scrollviewer

I have a tabControl which is contained inside a ScrollViewer with both Vertical and HorizontalScrollBarVisibility set to "Auto".
Just to better clarify what I have:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="280"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <!--Some Controls here-->
            </Grid>


            <TabControl Grid.Column=1 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=OneWay}" 
                BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
                Margin="-4,0,-5,-5"
                Style="{StaticResource STYLE_TabControl}"
                Name="tbControl1">

            </TabControl>
        </Grid>

</ScrollViewer>
```

If the tabItems's width is less then the TabControl's width everything works fine but if the tabItems's width exceed the size of the tabControl, the scrollviewer bar appears and all the tabControl stretches. 
What I would like to obtain is the default behaviour of the tabControl which is wrapping the tabItem in the header panel. 
Is there a way to obtain this even with a tabControl inside a scrollviewer?

Comment: Have you tried `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`?

Comment: ^ That should actually be `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`, my bad.

Comment: @lordpurple   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> that means according to your control size will be set

Comment: and tabcontrol and all the thing in first column ? Grid.column=0 ? Grid.column=1 ?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I missed the grid.column. I edited the code. What I would like to achieve is the tabControl to expand to the available space and the scroll appears if the space is not enough BUT the scroll should not appear if the tabItems are over the size of the tabControl